# PHP: cannot pass parameters to a function in another file

Tags: php

I have `file1.php` which gets data and want to return to the client-side. It loads another php file in at the top of itself: `require_once '/utils/file2.php';`

The function `returnJson()` is in the `file2.php` as below:

`function returnJson( $param1, $param2 ) {
    $res = [
        'timestamp' => time()
    ];
    if ( isset( $param1 ) ) $res['param1'] = $param1;
    if ( isset( $param2 ) ) $res['param2'] = $param2;
    echo json_encode( $res );
    exit;
}`

At the end of `file1.php` it calls `returnJson( $param1, $param2 )`. The `$param1` and `$param2` both have values.

Then on the client-side I have the json result only with the `timestamp` but missing the other two parameters.

`{
    "timestamp": 1470271525
}`

So I change the `returnJson` function to add the parameters in `$res` without checking:

`function returnJson( $param1, $param2 ) {
    $res = [
        'timestamp' => time(),
        'param1' => $param1,
        'param2' => $param2
    ];
    echo json_encode( $res );
    exit;
}`

Then on the client-side I got json like this:

`{
  "timestamp": 1470271525,
  "param1": null,
  "param2": null
}`

Comment: What do you mean by "not taking any parameters in"?  Describe the problem specifically.  Don't tell us what you assume the problem is, describe what indication you have that there is a problem in the first place.  Also, where/how do you call this function?  The code posted "doesn't take any parameters" because the function is never called.

Comment: Regarding the edit: It seems reasonable given this information that the values being passed to the function are `null`.  What makes you think they wouldn't be `null`?  Where do you set them?  What debugging have you done to confirm that these values are set?

Comment: I am sure they are not `null` because I `print_r()` just before pass them to the `returnJson()`.

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example to include that?  It just seems unlikely that *PHP itself* is broken, and more likely that there is a mistake in your code somewhere.  But without a more complete example you're just asking us to take your word for it that your code must be correct.  This makes for a potentially unanswerable question.

Comment: I found the `$param1` and `$param2` are both `null` now. So I will go fixing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the value of one or both parameters you're passing to the function, e.g. `returnJson($var1, $var2)`, is null, not that you're not passing them. `var_dump()` the variables *before* your function call, and `die()` to see what values they are. Then check for typos, follow their code path back to where they're set, etc.